Debugging Nx Mono-repo with NestJS Applications in Docker with VS Code Fails to Hit Breakpoints
Goal: I am trying to debug two NestJS applications running in a Nrwl Nx Monorepo setup, hosted inside Docker containers, using Visual Studio Code. My goal is to attach VS Code's debugger to these applications and successfully hit breakpoints.
Setup:
Applications: Two NestJS services (auth-gateway and notifications-gateway)
Development Environment: Node.js, Docker, Nrwl Nx, NestJS, TypeScript, and VS Code with the Node.js debugger.
Main Tools: Using the nx serve command within a docker-compose.yml file to run the applications. Running nx serve auth-gateway and nx serve notifications-gateway outside of docker allows for successful connection to the debugge.
Problem: Despite successful debugger connections outside Docker, breakpoints in VS Code are not being recognized when the applications run inside Docker containers. The debugger attaches without errors, but breakpoints do not trigger.
auth-gateway-1           | Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/4505cf30-66c7-40a8-8f6f-efed38504da6
auth-gateway-1           | For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

What I've Tried:
Docker Configuration: Configured docker-compose.yml to map debugging ports and ensure the correct startup commands for each service.
VS Code Debugger Configuration: Set up launch.json to attach to the correct ports and ensure proper source map handling.
TypeScript Configuration: Experimented with various tsconfig.json settings including adjustments to module and moduleResolution.
Command Adjustments: Initially attempted to use node --inspect directly and then switched back to using the Nx command (nx serve), which works outside Docker.
Local Debugging: Verified that debugging works locally without Docker, suggesting the issue is specific to the Docker environment.
Error Handling: Addressed TypeScript compilation errors related to configuration mismatches in moduleResolution.
Issues Encountered:
I tried switching from default nx serve commands to node with --inspect flag.
Here is a repo containing two sample NestJs projects in an Nx monorepo with the Dockerfile and docker-compose file.

Clone the repo: https://github.com/vdiaz1130/docker-debug
Run pnpm install
Ensure Docker is installed and running
Run docker compose up --watch
Open Debugger in Vs Code and attempt to connect

Questions:
How can I adjust Docker or VS Code configurations to ensure that breakpoints are recognized when debugging NestJS applications running in Docker?
Are there specific Docker or VS Code settings known to interfere with or facilitate debugging of TypeScript applications in this context? If so, are there work-arounds I can consider.
Looking for:
Insights into Docker configurations or VS Code settings that might be incorrectly set or missing, affecting the ability to hit breakpoints.
Recommendations for aligning Nrwl Nx commands with Docker for effective debugging.
I would even consider switching editors.
